# I`m Having a problem in Exporting Data to excel using application.transpose

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net, export, limit

This is my code in exporting data from database to excel using application.transpose but i search that it has limit of 64000 rows or array  how to export data greater than its limit?

Here is my code...

```
Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
            Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

            Dim adt As New MySqlDataAdapter("My Query", "My connection")
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            adt.Fill(dt)
            'Nombre de mesures  
            Dim Nbligne As Integer = dt.Rows.Count

            '(Write column headers and data)
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1 

                sheet.Cells(3, colIndex).Resize(Nbligne, ).Value = app.Application.transpose(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().[Select](Function(k) CObj(k(dc.ColumnName))).ToArray())
            Next
```

Comment: Let`s Say i have greater than 64000 of data how can i use application.transpose to export my data to excel?

Comment: Create a function to "flip" your array into the shape you need.  It will be much faster then populating cell-by-cell.

Comment: can you give me idea sir on how to execute that?

Comment: With a loop?  I'm not really a NET programmer, but you need to create an `Nbligne` x 1 2D array from whatever is the output from that expression you have inside `Transpose()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
Function TransposeArray1D(ByVal arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim tempArray As Variant
     ReDim tempArray(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), LBound(arr(0)) To UBound(arr(0)))
        For y = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            For x = LBound(arr(0)) To UBound(arr(0))
                tempArray(y, x) = arr(y)(x)
            Next x
        Next y
     TransposeArray1D = tempArray
End Function

Function TransposeArray2D(ByVal arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim tempArray As Variant
     ReDim tempArray(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2), LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1))
     For x = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
         For y = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
             tempArray(x, y) = arr(y, x)
         Next y
     Next x
     TransposeArray2D = tempArray
End Function

Function TransposeArrayIndex(ByVal arr As Variant, ByVal nTh As Long) As Variant
    Dim tempArray As Variant
    ReDim tempArray(0 To UBound(arr, 2))
         For y = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
             tempArray(y) = arr(nTh, y)
         Next y
     TransposeArrayIndex = tempArray
End Function
```